# angular 2 directive as npm package

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I've a directive that I want to publish on npm. I read [the doc here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages) and after that here is what I did:

- Copy the .js file that is compiled from the .ts file. ( I didn't copy the map file)
- Make new folder on desktop and paste it there
- `npm init` and `npm publish`
- create new project and `npm install --save-dev` my published package

However it doesn't find the name of the directive when I'm trying to declare it in the module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyDirective //this is not found
  ],
```

The js file appears in the module folder though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imported `import {...} from 'your-package-name/your-main-js';` it, right?

Here's a nice guide to create npm packages for Angular2.

https://medium.com/@OCombe/how-to-publish-a-library-for-angular-2-on-npm-5f48cdabf435#.coog6uf98

If you want to create a component package, remember to inline your templates/styles ! Otherwise your app will be broken..

Or you could use a script like this https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template to inline those templates/styles..

Maybe this repo as a starting point will help: https://github.com/mxii/ng2-offclick

You can also take a look at these resources:

- http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/
- http://myrighttocode.org/blog/typescript/angular2/components/npm/angular2-npm-components
- https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/52vz2b/how_to_publish_component_as_library/

Comment: You are right, its quite old guide.. but you have to read only the `npm stuff` .. before creating an package you should be able to install Angular2

Comment: You can take this repo as a starting point: https://github.com/mxii/ng2-offclick :)

Comment: Yeah that's those packages I installed at first before reading the tutorial, wasn't working either. I guess my issue is somewhere else, I'll keep digging, I'll accept the answer in any case

Comment: Thanks, but if there are any question, just ask.. hopefully the repo will help, take a look at the package.json for those angular2 packages.. its not just one! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone in the future might be struggling as I did here are the big steps.

1. npm init the folder so it has a `package.json` and add necessary devDependencies
2. compile .ts to js
3. tell npm to ignore .ts files in `.npmignore`:

> ```
>  node_modules
>  npm-debug.log
>  *.ts
>  !*.d.ts
> ```

I hope I didn't miss anything, in any case the tutorials above in the accepted answer will help